# Sorting Data for Matplotlib Surface Plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I’m trying to plot Riemann surface (imaginary part, real part is color-coded) for a complex valued function

[image: f(z)]

using `matplolib`.
As it follows from nature of complex multivalued function, when some path passes a branch cut

[image: branch_cut]

[image: branch_cuts]

its image jumps on `f(z)` plane.
As you can see in the code below, my mesh consists of circles

[image: paths]

in polar coordinate system, which are the paths, passing the branch cut. It results in a jump that you can see in the figure below.

**Question:**

Is there any way to stitch the parts of the plot in a proper way.
To me a possible solution looks like either:

- generate the values of mesh, bounded by the branch cut, and then concatenate the parts of them somehow (maybe even `matplotlib` itself has a function for it), or
- sort out z-axis values being obtained on a simple mesh, which I use in the code

I've tried both but not succeeded.

If anybody has already faced such issues, or has any ideas, I would appreciate your comments!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

k0 = 3 - 0.5j
# polar coordinates r and phi
Uphi = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.002) # phi from 0 to 2pi
Vr = np.arange(0,5,0.02)         # r from 0 to 5
# polar grid
U, V = np.meshgrid(Uphi, Vr)

# coordinates on conplex plane: Z = X + iY; X,Y - cartezian coords
X = V*np.cos(U)
Y = V*np.sin(U)

Z1 = np.imag(-np.sqrt(-k0**2 + (X + 1j*Y)**2)) # first branch of the multivalued function
Z2 = np.imag(+np.sqrt(-k0**2 + (X + 1j*Y)**2)) # second branch
Z = np.zeros((Z1.shape[0],2*Z1.shape[1])) # resultng array to plot
Z[:,:Z1.shape[1]] = Z1
Z[:,Z1.shape[1]:] = Z2

# colormap -- color-coding the imaginary part of the 4D function -- another dimension
Z_cv = np.zeros((Z1.shape[0],2*Z1.shape[1]))
Z_cv[:,:Z1.shape[1]] = np.real(-np.sqrt(-k0**2 + (X + 1j*Y)**2))
Z_cv[:,Z1.shape[1]:] = np.real(+np.sqrt(-k0**2 + (X + 1j*Y)**2))

# expanding grid for two branches Z1 and Z2
X1 = np.zeros((Z1.shape[0],2*Z1.shape[1]))
Y1 = np.zeros((Z1.shape[0],2*Z1.shape[1]))
X1[:,:Z1.shape[1]] = X
X1[:,Z1.shape[1]:] = X
Y1[:,:Z1.shape[1]] = Y
Y1[:,Z1.shape[1]:] = Y

# plotting the surface
F = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8),dpi=100)
A = F.gca(projection='3d',autoscale_on=True)
# normalizing the values of color map
CV = (Z_cv + np.abs(np.min(Z_cv)))/(np.max(Z_cv) + np.abs(np.min(Z_cv))) 

A.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z, rcount=100, ccount=200, facecolors=cm.jet(CV,alpha=.3))

A.view_init(40,70)
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m.set_array(Z_cv)
plt.colorbar(m)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

The following figures represent two regular branches of the function on the Riemann surface using using [Domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) approach. It more clearly shows those jumps.

```
import cplot
import numpy as np

cplot.show(lambda z: np.sqrt(z**2 - k0**2), -5, +5, -5, +5, 100, 100,alpha=0.7)
cplot.show(lambda z: -np.sqrt(z**2 - k0**2), -5, +5, -5, +5, 100, 100,alpha=0.7)
```

[image: branch cut]